# Encode only specific characters in String

Tags: java, string, character-encoding

I have to encode only some special characters in a string to numeric value.
Say,

```
String name = "test $#";
```

I want to encode only characters `$` and `#` in the above string. I tried using below code but it did not work out.

```
String encode = URLEncoder.encode(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(name), "UTF-8");
```

The encoded value will be like, for white space the encoded value is `&#160`

Comment: `&#160;` is a non-breaking space. You might test: `System.out.println("nbsp: " + name.equals("test\u00a0$#"));`

Comment: In this instance your white space is [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

Comment: Why are you using `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava`?

Comment: @Phylogenesis How can i convert this non-breaking space to &#160?

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do? First you run it through an encoder for Java, then you run it through an encoder for URIs.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Escapejava was done to escape the alphabets  and i think it is wrong way to do. My output should be "test&#160<encode value for $><encode value for #>"

Comment: `&#160;` is an [HTML entity](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp), not a URL encoded character (which would be `%a0` in this case). Which encoding do you actually want?

Comment: @Phylogenesis the outputof encoded string should be HTML entity values

Comment: Then you probably want to use [`StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml(java.lang.String))

Comment: @Phylogenesis Tried it but it is not converting space to &#160.. it converts < to &lt

Comment: In which case, you're going to have to write your own encoder. The non-breaking space is perfectly valid in HTML as it is without having to encode it as an entity.

Answer (score 0):

What about to split that String (by string#split method - with space as regex), from Array, which it returns you can use last item and you will get there symbols, what you need :)

```
String name = "test $#";
String nameSplittedArr = name.split(" ");
String yourChars = nameSplittedArr[nameSplittedArr.length-1]; //indexes from zero
```

That should works :)

Comment: it is just an example.. the special characters can be present anywhere in the string

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, I think you are after a customized encoding function. Something like:

```
public static String EncodeString(String text) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {
            sb.append(c);
        } else {
            sb.append("&#" + (int)c + ";");
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

An example of this is [here](http://ideone.com/7LxESZ).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I have already implemented like this.. but personally I don't want to convert the string to character array and do a for loop.. If I have 100 characters in my string then the loop will run for 100 times which can cause performance issues. So I want something like find and replace.

Comment: @AJJ Why would this necessarily result in performance issues? Any library function (such as `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava()`) would be implemented in the same way behind the scenes. If you want to check all characters, you *necessarily* need to check each character one by one.